# Activating a Specific Cell in Excel Using VBA Results to Error 400

Tags: vba, excel

I'm just getting all the text with red font-color on a first sheet and then stored it in an array. I then want to navigate to another sheet and activate a specific cell where I want to initially put the values inside my previous array. But the part where I activate a cell on the other sheet resulted to Error 400. I'm confident enough that it's right since I already used it before. I don't know if I have some manipulation at the first part of my code that affects that.

```
Sub isFontRed()
    Cells(2, 1).Select

    Dim missingJobs(0 To 600) As String
    Dim size As Integer, row As Integer, col As Integer, jobIndex As Integer
    jobIndex = 0

    For row = 2 To 10 '600
        For col = 1 To 2
            If (CStr(Cells(row, col).Font.ColorIndex) = 3) Then
               missingJobs(jobIndex) = Cells(row, col)
               jobIndex = jobIndex + 1
           End If
       Next col
    Next row

    Dim jobs As String
    jobs = ""
    For i = 0 To UBound(missingJobs) - 1
        jobs = jobs + missingJobs(i) + ", "
    Next i

    Worksheets("New Jobs in New Folder").Activate
    Cells(4, 2).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it give an error description as well, or just the 400? (reading up, that is a thing).  I've read:  _400 errors are, by definition, unspecified and (for all intents and purposes) mysterious_, I've also read: _this error is typically caused by having the add-in file for the Spreadsheet Assistant for Excel 2003 installed as in add-in in Excel 2007 or Excel 2010_.  I was going to ask if the _New Jobs in New Folder_ sheet exists, but that would give a 424 Object Required error.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but are you trying to select cells(4, 2)?  I don't think you can 'activate' a cell like you can a worksheet.  Try Cells(4, 2).Select instead.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the  activate function. The sub function above was written inside the sheet and when I transfer it to a module it works. I guess there is something to where you place your code like in sheet level or module level.

Comment: Ahh ok.  Have you tried Activesheet.cells(3,2).activate?  Like you say, it might be some strange issue with scoping.